# nginx forward to tomcat if file does not exist

Tags: nginx

I successfully had nginx forward everything to tomcat. Now I want to have a static html page running on 'myserver.com' and my tomcat app under app.myserver.com.

As there are already links out in the internet that do not point to app.myserver.com I need to handle that somehow.

Basicly the idea is to let nginx check if the static html file for the request exists.
If it doesn't exist it should forward it to tomcat (i.e. @app). This is my current configuration.

```
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files / $uri @app;
}


location @app {

#
# Forward SSL so that Tomcat knows what to do
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_pass http://tomcat1/;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
#proxy_redirect off;
proxy_connect_timeout      240;
proxy_send_timeout         240;
proxy_read_timeout         240;
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
2017/03/24 20:49:12 [emerg] 7639#0: "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myserver.com:134
```

What's my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the URI from the `proxy_pass` statement. Use:

```
proxy_pass http://tomcat1;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Also, the `try_files` statement should not have a bare `/` within it. Use:

```
try_files $uri @app;
```